# Keep UIImageView and UILabel center aligned

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uilabel, autolayout

I have a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` placed side by side at the center of the screen through XIB, Now the label text can be small/large, its dynamic, image is constant.

When the label text is small, image and label look center aligned, but when label text is large, image remains center aligned, but now the label tail almost touches the screen.

Here is the image:

[image]

Hope you have got this, how can I make this two (image and label) center aligned always.

Comment: I'm no expert in auto layout, but isn't this just a manner of 'ctrl + click & drag' from one view to the other and set a center alignment constraint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)alignImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView andLabel:(UILabel *)label inSuperView:(UIView *)superView {
  [label sizeToFit]; // Resize the label to have a frame that perfectly fit the content
  /* We first set the X origin of the imageView,
   * To center anything on the X axis, the common way is to say that x is "(superview.width - subview.width) / 2"
   * Here subview width is imageView.width + label.width
   */
  [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake((superView.frame.size.width - imageView.frame.size.width - label.frame.size.width) / 2, imageView.frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];
   /* According to the previous calculation, we just have to say that the x origin for the label is just at the end of the imageView (origin + size)
    */
  [label setFrame:CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x + imageView.frame.size.width, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: Hello, it worked, but isnt their a easier way, if not can you explain me how did you arrived at this solution.Bcoz, this case we require in most situations.

Comment: @Ranjit add comments, hope it will be easier to understand :) !

Comment: @KIDdAe just to make it more generic, you could replace self.view by imageView.superview. Then it works even if the superview is not the UIViewController root view. The only thing that matters is that imageView and label are children of the same view.

Comment: @VictorMaiaAldecôa Indeed, I've Added a third argument corresponding to the superview. Using `imageView.superView` means that the imageView is already a subview of the superview. Then I preferred to write something completely generic :) !

Comment: Hello @KIDdAe, I have case were, both are labels, but in the above case, you see one is image and label.So the text of both can vary in length, but I want them center aligned, so how to do this.

Comment: @Ranjit I guess calling `sizeToFit` for the second label at the start of the method (and for the first one like in the sample provided in the answer) should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XIB you should use auto layout to set your constraints. Hold the ctrl key while click and dragging from one view to the other and choose the option you want.

[image: autolayoutbox]

Comment: I am not using auto layout